# Laravel $user->notifications return null

Tags: laravel, notifications

I'm trying to get the notifications for a user. But when i the method get() in my NotificationController start it's always return null. This this the actual code i'm using to debug this feature :

```
 function get(){

    $user = \App\User::find(12);

    dd($user->notifications);

}
```

The route is with POST method, i use Postman to test it. I always get error 500 with null content.
Do you know why ?
Thank's in advance

**[EDIT]**
This is the result of dd($user) for the get() method with POST request :

```
{ 
"id": 13, 
"rang": 1, 
"image": "https://www.drupal.org/files/profile_default.jpg", 
"firstname": "Donald", 
"lastname": "Torp", 
"email": "ashlynn.mcclure@pacocha.com", 
"created_at": null, 
"updated_at": null 
}
```

This is the content of my DB notifications table actually :

```
ID : e7f54269-a5ff-4109-9b8a-c2328fb6cf98   
Type : App\Notifications\IdeaSelected   
notifiable_type : App\Idea  
notifiable_id : 13  
data : {"idea":{"id":39,"name":"okeefe","description":"Sunt soluta et eum. Vitae sint adipisci et excepturi eos est exercitationem velit. Mollitia hic aut aperiam cum incidunt dolorem sed. Ut blanditiis eos temporibus hic illum quis.","image":"https:\/\/lorempixel.com\/400\/280\/?98265","user":13,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}}     
read_at :   
created_at : 2018-04-14 00:57:37
```

Result for `return (dd($user->load('notifications')));` :

```
#relations: array:1 [
    "notifications" => DatabaseNotificationCollection {#549
      #items: []
    }
  ]
```

Result if i change the notifiable_type from App\Idea to App\User :

```
[
    {
        "id": "e7f54269-a5ff-4109-9b8a-c2328fb6cf98",
        "type": "User::class",
        "notifiable_type": "App\\User",
        "notifiable_id": 13,
        "data": {
            "idea": {
                "id": 39,
                "name": "okeefe",
                "description": "Sunt soluta et eum. Vitae sint adipisci et excepturi eos est exercitationem velit. Mollitia hic aut aperiam cum incidunt dolorem sed. Ut blanditiis eos temporibus hic illum quis.",
                "image": "https://lorempixel.com/400/280/?98265",
                "user": 13,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            }
        },
        "read_at": null,
        "created_at": "2018-04-14 00:57:37",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-14 00:57:37"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you give us more info about the relationships.

Comment: @StefanoGroenland I added the notifiable attribute to User Class and this this my IdeaSelected.php file (Notification classe) :
`class IdeaSelected extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $idea;
    public function __construct(Idea $idea)
    {
        $this->idea = $idea;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'idea_id' => $this->idea->id,
            'idea_name' => $this->idea->name,
        ];
    }
}`

Comment: You mean the notifiable trait?

Comment: Yes the trait, sorry. This one :
`class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
`

Comment: And if you dd($user) you get a user, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah i see you are assigning the notifiable_type incorrectly it should say the User::class

**When defining the notifiable model think to what you are sending an notification**

Comment: Should i replace "App\Idea" by "User::class" ??

Comment: Yes if thats the value you pass to notifiable_type

Comment: So the end result will be App\User

Comment: Ohhh !! Now i have a return ! Just look in the question this the result

Comment: Great! Didn't noticed it until you gave the return haha.. so for further ref. When defining the notifiable model think to what you are sending an notification

Comment: Please mark the answer as an answer to your question for other people so see!

Comment: Yes ! Thank youso much for you time @Stefano ! I marked this question as answer. Thank's again !

Comment: No problem mate! Goodluck coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grab the notificationse once you store them in your database.

Take a look at the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#database-notifications

Comment: Yes, i agree. The notify work fine ! All notifications are in the DB but i can't grab them. And yes i follew the official document, that's why i'm posting here :/

Comment: Yep, i used `php artisan notifications:table`

Comment: And you also ran php artisan migrate after that?

Comment: Yep i ran this command. The table has been created and i can fill it with notify()

Comment: And can you show me what dd($user) gives back? Please update your question with some markup

Comment: This is the result of dd($user) for the get() method :  
`{  
    "id": 13,  
    "rang": 1,  
    "image": "https://www.drupal.org/files/profile_default.jpg",  
    "firstname": "Donald",  
    "lastname": "Torp",  
    "email": "ashlynn.mcclure@pacocha.com",  
    "created_at": null,  
    "updated_at": null  
}`  

What do you mean by markup ? (Sorry i'm new here)

Comment: @ebillis an empty string?

Comment: No problem,  i mean like you did with the get() in your question makes it easier to read for us here

Comment: And you have some notifications for user with id 13?

Comment: Uhh are you even assigning an user to the notifications table?

Comment: Ok i see, but in comment section the code markup doesn't line break i don't know why... Even if i double space at the end of line.  

Yeah there is three line in the DB with notifiable_id equal to 13.  

Assigning an user mean to write is ID in notifiable_id column right ?

Comment: Can you check if you see the notifications when you dd($user->load('notifications'));

Comment: It's return me some informations about the user (More than dd($user)).
I've post the result in the question